# Does quantum decoherence happened in the process towards thermal equilibrium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, decoherence, quantum-statistics

In Kardar's "statistical physics of particles" and some other books about statistical physics I've read, when dealing with quantum statistics, they just give the conclusion that the density matrix of the canonical ensemble is $\rho=Z^{-1}*e^{-\beta H}$, basically the same as the classical situation.

My question is, why there is no coherence term between different eigenstate of Hamiltonian, is some mechanism of decoherence happened in the process towards thermal equilibrium? If so, what's the mechanism, and why it can cause such decoherence?

Comment: Decoherence in a finite system is strictly speaking not enough for thermal equilibrium (or any other truly irreversible process), but it's very much related to the classical Poincare recurrence theorem and it leads to effectively "infinitely long" recurrence time scales. It's therefor probably "good enough" for most practical situations. The more interesting question is how we get to real irreversibility and the answer to that is "through infinite phase space volume".